What is the role of this suffix for an opamp?
I'm trying to figure out the difference between OP484FSZ and OP484ESZ. Seems both have the same footprint as 14-Lead SOIC_N. Here is the datasheet.
Does it mean one of them has lower input offset voltage? The table is not aligned well so hard to be sure which one is more precise.

The only difference I see is the offset voltage at the 5V and 3V supply, plus  TCVos (temperature coefficient of offset voltage) is only guaranteed and only has a typical number with +/-15V supplies for the 'E' grade.

These would typically be 'binned' parts. The ones that measure as low Vos are sold as 'E' and others which may be not good enough for 'E' or may be good enough are sold as 'F'. Usually low Vos is an indicator of low TCVos since the matching is close. They may well guarantee the 2uV/K by characterization rather than actual 100% testing.
n.b. you have to dig deeper to find out what they mean by 2uV/°C. Often it's not what you might hope for (the maximum slope of Vos vs. temperature curve over temperature), but rather a 'box' around the curve covering the entire temperature range, so the local slope may be higher.
I don't see an issue with the alignment of the table. The smaller number (above the other) refers to the maximum offset voltage at default ambient temperature Ta = 25°C (as measured 500 milliseconds after power-on, so maybe not all the self-heating). The larger number below that is the maximum offset voltage over the whole working temperature range from -40°C to +125°C.
So, for example, the 'E' grade of 184/284 has an offset voltage of maximum +/-100uV at 25°C and +/-200uV maximum over the whole operating temperature range.

It might help the readers if you say what TCVos and Vos are. Also, he was curious about OP484 as he had trouble seeing which value is for which, so mentioning that OP484E has 150uV while OP484F has 250uV maximum offset voltage (Vos), and then 300uV and 500uV respectively over the whole range of operating temperatures.

@EdinFifić good comments, edited, thanks.
